# Skip .rdlc file compiling on build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, clickonce, rdlc

I'm using VS 2013 Express. I have a legacy project that uses .rdlc files loaded during runtime. They are stored in ..\Reports directory. These files have some custom code and reference external modules. When I build the project with these files property `[Build Action] = "None"`, there is no issue and they are correctly loaded and displayed during runtime.

Problem starts when I need to publish the project as a ClickOnce app. To include .rdlc files in ClickOnce, I have to change their `[Build Action] = "Content"`. After this, VS starts to spellcheck .rldc files and gives me a bunch of errors I don't care about, since I know that at the runtime when those files are loaded these errors do not occur.

How can I tell VS to include these files as a content without the spellcheck on build?

---

Just for info - the errors i'm getting are

> "Error while loading code module"

and

> "<Namespace-name> cannot be resolved"

in the custom code. None of these are an issue during runtime

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to move forward by following the very last reply in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d1d536a-8fdd-43e3-9616-d3e46f02ea8b/visual-studio-2012-rdlc-with-external-reference-bug?forum=vsreportcontrols) and adding my external library to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin". Main question remains - shouldn't there be a way to simply copy .rdlc files in clickonce installer without building them?